# Installation of sympy for python in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I am remotely accessing RaspberryPi from my laptop via SSH.

When I run a Test_sympy.py file in Raspberry Pi desktop and import sympy it runs pretty well as shown below:

[image]

However, when I access this file via putty, it shows no module named sympy. Why does the code does not run in putty. Can somebody plz help me out with this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one FUNDAMENTAL difference between Thonny and your command line example. Thonny uses **python3 - yet you are calling python i.e. python2**.

Forget python - it is DEAD. Use `python2` or `python3`, and python2 certainly won't be the default in future Debian releases.

Incidentally putty is a red herring - it has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I think you meant "forget Python 2" in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Your CLI entry: `sudo python /home/pi/Test_sympy.py` is calling `/usr/bin/python2` instead of `/usr/bin/python3`. You can see some of this by listing all `python` files in `/usr/bin` (via `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python`). The system is configured to use python2 as the default for `python`.

#### Change default Python version for the system:

If you want to make `python3` the **default** version system-wide, you can use the `update-alternatives` package:

```bsh
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

When this is run, it has the effect that any references to `python` call for `python3` instead of `python2`. For example:

```bsh
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Also, the `update-alternative` choice is reversible:

```bsh
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 10
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2.7 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

#### Change default Python version for a user:

If you want to leave the system default for Python as-is, but want to use Python3 as the default for your user id, you may create an *alias*:

1. Open `~/.bashrc` in your editor:

   ```bsh
   $ nano ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add the alias to `~/.bashrc`; then save `~/.bashrc` & close the editor:

   ```
   alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
   ```
3. Source the change to your current shell session:

   ```bsh
   $ . ~/.profile

   --OR--

   $ source ~/.profile
   ```